# Identical Parcel methods?

Tags: java, android, classloader, parcelable

`readList` documentation:

> Read into an existing List object from the parcel at the current
>   dataPosition(), using the given class loader to load any enclosed
>   Parcelables. If it is null, the default class loader is used.

`readTypedList` documentation:

> Read into the given List items containing a particular object type
>   that were written with writeTypedList(List) at the current
>   dataPosition(). The list must have previously been written via
>   writeTypedList(List) with the same object type.

I have a couple questions because i'm confused with where each is used:

1. What is fundamentally the difference between using these two methods (with their corresponding `write` methods of course)?
2. In what situations is one used over the other - or can either be used to marshall/unmarshall lists?
3. Why does `readList` take a `ClassLoader` parameter, while `readTypedList` take a `CREATOR` parameter (the anonymous inner class defined) - what's the specific reason for this?